# How to exit application if database takes too long to respond

Tags: c#, database

i have database query: `datareader.execQuery("select * from table");`
However sometimes database takes too long to respond and is stuck at this line.
if this happens my application should exit

Thanks guys but i need to know:
Is there any way i can achieve this using Stopwatch or Timer??

Comment: but why on earth is it taking hell lot of time? Production database on production server which is always busy? Or lame database? or why? Just a food for thought...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set the CommandTimeout on your SqlCommand object. If the timeout is exceeded, you will get an exception. You can catch this, and exit your app, if that is what you want to do.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout.aspx

"Gets or sets the wait time before terminating the attempt to execute a command and generating an error."

Answer (score 1):

A cleaner way will be to set the [SqlCommand.CommandTimeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout.aspx) property by default it is 30 secs

You will have to handle the TimeOut Exception